# Long running process in separate thread updating UI

Tags: android, long-running-processes

I noticed a similar problem for dot NET, but my problem is for Android, so perhaps solution looks different.

The process is activated by clicking button. The process was running as part of UI thread and at the end it did updating UI. I have added progress dialog to be more user friendly, so I instantiate a thread running the process and at the end it updates UI and dismisses progress dialog. Unfortunately UI update is failing with the exception below:

```
07-19 21:14:04.602: ERROR/Atjeews(283): android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

If I try to block UI thread and release it after long process finishes to update UI, the progress dialog doesn't get shown. Should I try to show progress dialog in a separate thread instead, or there is another simpler solution?

Answer (score 1):

please check http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html

Comment: @Dmitriy R i recommends you to Use AsyncTask in android for doing such type of work as riser said to check link follow that you will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from the Android Developers [Processes and Threads](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html) page:

> To fix this problem, Android offers several ways to access the UI thread from other threads. Here is a list of methods that can help:
>
> Activity.runOnUiThread(Runnable)
> View.post(Runnable)
> View.postDelayed(Runnable, long)

You can just instantiate an anonymous Runnable as the argument, like `post(new Runnable(){doWhatever();})`, that will do whatever you want on the UI thread instead.

Comment: Sorry, the system doesn't allow to do me these actions, because of my bad reputation.

Comment: Well, that sounds like something is wrong with the system. You have more than the required 15 reputation to up-vote. Also, I believe you can accept an answer even with only 1 rep. You should talk to someone about that (maybe on meta or something), because it can damage your chances of getting useful answers.